# Can't Import a Json Array to Mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a **jsonArray** to a **mongoDB** with windows command prompt.

My command is,

```
C:\mongo>mongoimport --jsonArray -d testdb -c testcollection -f my_test_file.json
```

The file **my_test_file.json** does exist at **C:\mongo** and the file contains following,

```
[{"id": 1, "data":"test"}]
```

The output of the command prompt is only `connected to: 127.0.0.1` and no import happens.

The command promt that runs the **db** says `connection accepted` when I ran the command above.

Can anyone notice what I'm missing here?

Comment: Is your ID column in your database configured as a numeric type?  If not, you should put quotes around the 1 as well.

Comment: Thanks @ZacWolf. The id is numeric. I tried changing it to `"1"`. still not working..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flag "-f" indicates fields but not file as I assume you thought. Just remove it from your command and everything should work just fine.

```
C:\mongo>mongoimport --jsonArray -d testdb -c testcollection my_test_file.json
```